# Static variables in web requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, static-members

How a static public variable in a static public class behaves between web requests in a C# MVC3 web project. Those types of variables mantain there values between requests or not?

Comment: Yes value will be retained in between requests and across users, but its not a good idea to use them (actually it depends), we face a lot of issues in my project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your question in its simplest form; yes. Anything that's static will persist:

- Between requests
- Across all users

They *won't* be shared between different instances of the same application (e.g. in a load balanced scenario) and they *will* lose their values when the application pool recycles.

Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to try and persist state using static variables unless you have a very specific reason to do so.

If you are considering using static variables to save user-specific data between requests, *don't*. Because they are shared across threads (and therefore across both requests and users), you will introduce race conditions as soon as you have more than one user.

Opt for another form of storage, such as session state, cookies or - better still - a database.

Comment: Good answer. Using `static` variables is the worst idea when it comes to user sensitive data.

Comment: I just want handle values that are global to the web application (the same value for all the users) and that are changed not very often. Is there another way that don't need accessing the Data Base every time we want read the value?

Comment: @miguelbgouveia: In that case it is a good possibility to use that, but be sure about referencing other classes that might contain sensitive data.

Comment: @miguelbgouveia If you're serving up global data and just want to avoid extraneous DB calls, think about storing the information in a DB or on the filesystem and using a singleton: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx